# write/wall: how to prevent non-printable characters from being escaped

Tags: write

Compare

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=512 count=4
```

to

```
write lsr < <(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=512 count=4)
```

How do I achieve the intended behaviour? Current output:

```
Message from qwe@hhgw11 on pts/386 at 17:37 ...
^[\305^\I\216\372\265\204\257\244+\277^X\334\303\273\261\200\253\323g\
...S\322EOF
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this???

Comment: This _is_ the intended behaviour. By the author(s) of the `write` utility.

Comment: @derobert "Why?" Because other users' `$HOME`s aren't always visible to each other, and we needed to pass some source code around. Non-binary formats are inefficient and time-consuming. What alternative is there for users to communicate outside of the filesystem apart from `wall`?

Comment: @user234461 Sockets would be a normal way. You could also use a FIFO (though that's inside the filesystem, but it could be somewhere visible to both of you, e.g., `/tmp`). You could also, if you insist on using wall for this, Base64 or uuencode the data first. But really, if you want to share source code... use a version control system like git.

Comment: @derobert So the only way of passing binary messages between users is to either add `base64` to the command every time on both ends, manually negotiate a socket over `write` in advance, or make everything world-readable?

Comment: @user234461: Why does your source code contain non-printable characters?  Why not just *copy* your file to ```/tmp``` and let the other user copy it from there? And don't you have email?

Comment: @user234461 There are a bunch of solutions that already exist. But `write` is intended for quick communication with other logged-in users—it isn't a file transfer tool. Abusing it for one must be painful—how do you get the contents in to a file on the receiving end? Copy and paste?

Comment: You should also be able to mail files to each other if you give `mail` the `-a` option to create an attachment. It might use some type of encoding, but your mail user agents will take care if that transparently.

Answer (score 5):

Being able to send control characters (other than a few safe ones like newline and tab) to another user's terminal would be a security bug, so there shouldn't be a way.

Comment: Well in that case, `wall` has a security bug, because newlines and tabs are control characters.

Comment: @user234461 True, those are control characters. Edited to fix.